# Angular 6 Lazy Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular6

I am using below code for lazy loading

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'manager', loadChildren: './manager/manager.module#ManagerModule' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
]
```

I am getting below error

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function**

If I run the project with **ng serve --aot** it works but if I run **npm start it start** throwing error

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9825

Comment: rather than using ng server do we have any fix ?

Comment: This issue only happens during development - when you do a production build and deploy the loading works as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found issue, issue what that when I create component from angular cli it was getting added to the app component and I was calling children component in routing. So it was creating loop and it was getting error. Now it is resolved